# Updating checkbox value in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a Shiny app that does the following:

1) Upload a file like this:

```
X   Y
1   3
2   1
3   6
4   4
```

2) Press a `Run` button to add 2 to the file values by default, or multiplying by 2 if a box is checked,

3) Making a scatter plot out of the generated values.

My problems are (i) I need to check/uncheck the box and then press again the `Run` button to display the corresponding plot, and (ii) the checkbox comes back to `on` every time.

How could I update the plot when I check/uncheck the box without pressing the `Run` button?
I tried to place the `observe()` and `updateCheckboxInput()` function outside the `eventReactive()` block, but it does simply not work.

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)



ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput(
        inputId = "input_file",
        label = "Choose an input file"
    ),
    actionButton(
        inputId = "run_button",
        label = "Run"
    ),
    checkboxInput(
        inputId = "operation_button",
        label = "multiply instead of summing",
        value = FALSE
    ),
    plotOutput(
        outputId = "my_plot"
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    my_data <- eventReactive(
        input$run_button,
        {
            inFile <- input$input_file
            if(is.null(inFile)){
                return(NULL)
            }

            my_in <- read.table(inFile$datapath, header = T, sep = "\t")

            my_function <- function(input, operation){
                if(operation == "sum"){
                    input <- input + 2
                }else if(operation == "multiply"){
                    input <- input * 2
                }

                return(input)
            }

            button_switch <- ifelse(input$operation_button == FALSE, "sum", "multiply")

            observe(
                {
                    updateCheckboxInput(session, "operation_button", "multiply instead of summing", value = button_switch)
                }
            )

            my_in <- my_function(my_in, button_switch)

        }
    )



    output$my_plot <- renderPlot(
        {
        my_df <- my_data()

        ggplot(my_df, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
        geom_point()
        }
    )
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: glad it works! An upvote is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `eventReactive()` dependent on multiple inputs:

```
my_data <- eventReactive(c(input$run_button, input$operation_button),...)
```